# Flask decorator not properly applied

Tags: python, flask

I tried using a decorator to handle my login, but it doesn't seem to work, I feel like I may misunderstand how it works.

So, this below works fine :

```py
@app.route("/<username>")
def user_home(username):
    """
    Home page for validated users.

    """
    if not (session.get(username) or session.get("admin")):
        if not username:
            return redirect(url_for("login"))
        else:
            abort(401)
    return render_template("map.html", 
                           title=lang["map"], 
                           username=username, 
                           nav="bootstrap/navigation.html", 
                           **lang)
```

But, to avoid using this code on every function, I tried to implement it this way, to apply the `@login_required` for each function necessitating the login :

```py
def login_required(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def decorated_function(*args, **kwargs):
        username = session.get("logged_in")
        if not (session.get(username) or session.get("admin")):
            if not username:
                return redirect(url_for("login"))
            else:
                abort(401)
        return f(*args, **kwargs)
    return decorated_function


@app.route("/<username>")
@login_required
def user_home(username):
    """
    Home page for validated users.

    """
    return render_template("map.html", 
                           title=lang["map"], 
                           username=username, 
                           nav="bootstrap/navigation.html", 
                           **lang)
```

But, this way everyone seems to be able to see other peoples pages... What did I get wrong ?

Comment: It doesn't look like your code ever confirms that a user is requesting their own data. As long as someone is logged in, they can request any `/<username>` route.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Semantics of session parameters are not that evident, without seeing how logging in is implemented. I assume that an authenticated user gets his or her login as a key in session data. And skip the part where `logged_in` is only used in the decorator.

Your initial code deals with `username` taken from path parameters. It seems your decorator code lost that part. To extract that parameter value, you may use [inspect](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.getcallargs) libraty. The decorator may look like this. `login_required` was replaced with `authorisation_required` to better describe the conditions applied.

```py
from inspect import getcallargs


def authorisation_required(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def decorated_function(*args, **kwargs):
        inspection = getcallargs(f, *args, **kwargs)
        username = inspection["username"]  # <<< get the username from arguments
        if not (session.get(username) or session.get("admin")):
            if not username:
                return redirect(url_for("login"))
            else:
                abort(401)
        return f(*args, **kwargs)
    return decorated_function
```

Comment: Yes, that was that. I forgot that in the decorator context, username wasn't pulled from the URL. Thanks a lot for your reply !